# Moving from wordpress website

Tags: web-development, wordpress

Is there an easy way to move a blog from wordpress website i.e. at

```
http://myblog.wordpress.com/
```

to my independent domain i.e

```
www.mywebsite.com
```

Comment: Do you want to actually host the site yourself, or just make it accessible via your own domain?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind keeping the site with wordpress.com, you can just get the domain name added to your account. It costs http://en.wordpress.com/products/

Answer (score 0):

If you're moving to another host with Wordpress already setup, you can [export your blog](http://en.support.wordpress.com/export/) from Wordpress.com and use the Import functionality under Tools->Import on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you mean a redirect from mywebsite.com to mywebsite.wordpress.com.
No, not an easy one-step procedure if you want to switch to self-hosted wordpress. 
Exporting and importing the data is the easy part, if you use any plugins or themes. But it works fine in principle.